# Leaking pipe in basement ceiling

Tags: plumbing, leak

The other day I noticed that our drywall was saturated and having removed it found an open ended pipe above it was leaking. The thing is I have absolutely no idea what this pipe is or why it has just started leaking. I can cap it but I don't want to until I have some idea as to why it is there and where the water is coming from. I can't see where the other end goes (due to its location) but it appears to go into the wall of the house. However there is nothing on the exterior of the house on the other side of the pipe. Has anyone got any ideas of what this pipe could be for?

It does look like somebody may have "capped" the pipe before as there is some residue on the end of it. Is it likely that somebody did a poor job and the "cap" that they put there has now failed? Still, if this is the case why does the pipe exist and where would the water be coming from?

I should mention the house was rebuilt about 5 years ago on the top of a basement of a 40 year old house that was knocked down.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Shows the pipe [image]

Shows the end of the pipe and the possible "cap" [image: Shows the end of the pipe and the possible "cap"]

Shows where the pipe goes into the (wall)[image]

Comment: The orientation of your first picture is extremely confusing. Can you adjust this picture so that the basement ceiling is at the top?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Point taken. I have now turned the photo round. The brown spots seen in the photo are on the ceiling.